# Add gift card to apple wallet

Tags: wallet, gift

I have been given some Apple Gift Cards and would like to add them to my apple wallet. This used to be done via scanning a code on the back of the card with the wallet app. Adding gift cards received via email is still possible by tapping the "Add to Wallet" button.

How can I do this with a physical gift card now?

Comment: You should be able to add it directly in the App Store app

Comment: Apple Gift Cards have been combined with iTunes Gift Cards, and since then you load the balance onto your Apple ID to store it digitally.

Comment: I’ve been trying to do this for a while now and it seems apple wants to suck down your gift card credit as purchases, so anything added to your account credit will gradually get used up as subscriptions get paid for. I wish this wasn’t the case as adding cards to the wallet makes so much sense.